# How can ZGC avoid to scan the large local cache to reduce the concurrent mark time of GC cycle?

Tags: java, jvm, zgc

There is a 3GB local cache in my service（the total mem of my server is 16GB）, by using ZGC in JDK11, I found out that the concurrent mark time is too long in each cycle(almost 5 seconds if there are 2 concurrent threads).

So I'm wondering if there is a way that ZGC just skips marking this local cache?

I have already tried dividing this local cache into two layers of cache, the first layer is Caffeine, and the second layer is off-heap Cache. But it didn't work.

Comment: There isn't a way.  ZGC is not a generational collector.  But it shouldn't matter how long marking takes.  Apart from the (short) "stop the world" period when ZGC is finding the roots, your application can run as normal while the marking proceeds in the background.  Unfortunately, the only way to speed up marking is to add more threads (cores!) to do the marking.

Comment: However, 5 seconds to mark 3GB sounds like a long time.  Are you sure that there isn't something else wrong; e.g. insufficient physical RAM leading to paging?

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! Yes, my application can run as normal while the marking proceeds in the background, but if the cycle of ZGC is too long, maybe in the process of one cycle, the ZGC would begin another round of GC(since the alloction rate is too fast). And then it will cause allocation stall. So I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid the local cache to be marked to reduce the time of each cycle

Comment: You can't do that.  ZGC marks / collects everything.  It is not generational.  But if cycles are taking too long you could increase the number of GC threads; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/z-garbage-collector1.html#GUID-CD1DF73A-11D2-4478-BE14-20CBF8DA2830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can ZGC avoid to scan the large local cache to reduce the concurrent mark time of GC cycle?

It can't.  ZGC will mark and collect the entire heap and there's no way to change that.

Since ZGC is not generational, it is *technically impossible* to do a partial collection *safely*.  Any reachable object in the portion of the heap that you don't mark could reference any of the objects in portion that you are collecting.  Including any that are not otherwise reachable.  So if ZGC didn't mark the entire heap, reachable objects could be deleted!

If your problem is that GC cycles are taking too long, your options are:

- Increase the number of concurrent GC threads.
- Decrease heap size.
- Find and fix any possible external causes of memory and CPU contention; e.g. making sure that you actually have 16GB of *actual* RAM ... rather than over-committed RAM provided by a hypervisor.

You could also try using G1GC instead.

Or you could rearchitect your service so that you can run multiple instances; e.g. by [sharding](https://www.techtarget.com/searchoracle/definition/sharding) the data in the service.